# NodeJS Router request.body.id при Get возвращает undefined

Tags: node.js, express

При get запросе request.body.id равно undefined.

BodyParser подключен, пробовал по разному кидать запрос (/:id, /id, /?id=***), но при каждом результат undefined.

Кусок кода из server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

........

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

........

app.use(function(req,res,next)
{
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, \ Authorization');
next();
});

........

var apiRoutes = require('./app/routes/api')(app, express);
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

Кусок кода из /app/routes/api.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Page = require('../models/page.js');
var adminUser = require('../models/admin-users.js');

module.exports = function (app, express) {

var apiRouter = express.Router();

........

/**
 * delete a single page
 */
apiRouter.get('/pages/delete/:id', function (request, response) {

    var id = request.body.id;

    Page.remove({
            _id: id
        },
        function (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        });
    return response.send('Page id- ' + id + 'has been deleted');
});

/**
 * displaying a single record
 */
apiRouter.get('/pages/admin-details/:id', function (request, response) {

    var id = request.body.id;

    Page.findOne({
            _id: id
        },

        function (err, page) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            return response.send(page);

        });
});

//return apiRouter to app
return apiRouter;

};
```

При дебаге в обеих функциях роутера на строке

```
var id = request.body.id;
```

id равно undefined.

Сам request.body исправный.

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что значение из маршрута попадет в `req.body`? Оно и не должно туда попадать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значения URL-параметров нужно считывать следующим образом:

```
var id = request.params.id;
```

Документация: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params

Comment: Думаю стоит добавить ссылку на документацию http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Спасибо, добавил ссылку на всегда актуальную версию документации.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена. Документацию обязательно перечитаю.